# A line or a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subspace if and only if it passes through the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I read online on [this ppt](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-2011A/Lect2-02web.pdf)., pg. 9 that,

"A line or a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subspace if and only if it passes through the origin."

Why is this true?

Answer (score 3):

Subspaces must contain the identity $\mathbf{0}$, so that handles the "only if" direction.

The other direction takes a little more work.  With a line through the origin, parameterize the points and check that you get a subspace.  This is most easily done by choosing a nonzero vector on the line and checking that it generates the line the same way a basis would.  Do the same for a plane, but choose independent vectors in "different" directions.  In either case, you should be able to verify the subspace test/axioms pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec 0$ must be in any subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ by definition.